# Can a Flow check if a field was attempted to be updated, even if value is the same?

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow

I am using the REST API to upsert records by external ID, and I have a Flow that triggers on update. I have a field `Refresh_Date__c` that I want to default to today's date on update using the flow, unless the API received a value for that field.

The issue is when the API receives a value that equals what the record already had saved. I have a decision condition of [`$Record.Refresh_Date__c` `Is Changed` `True`], but if the REST API payload contains a value that happens to be the same as the field's current value, that condition is false.

Is there a way to check if the update "touched" or included a certain field, whether or not the field's value changed? In other words, if the API request payload contains ANY `Refresh_Date__c` value, the condition would be true, but if that field is missing, it would be false. Hoping to be able to solve without a custom APEX endpoint.